# What's the XML file that comes together with a .NET assembly file?

Tags: .net, xml, .net-assembly

Many .NET assemblies are accompanied with an XML file. For example, `System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll` comes together with `System.Web.WebPages.Razor.xml` that contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<doc>
   <assembly>
       <name>System.Web.WebPages.Razor</name> 
   </assembly>
   <members>
       <member name="T:System.Web.WebPages.Razor.PreApplicationStartCode" /> 
       <member name="M:System.Web.WebPages.Razor.PreApplicationStartCode.Start" /> 
       <member name="T:System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider" /> 
       <member name="M:System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.#ctor" />
        Much more elements follow...
   </members>
</doc>
```

What's this XML for? Do I need it in runtime?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is the code comments / IntelliSense file, and is used by the IDE (i.e. Visual Studio), not the runtime - it is where all the extended method / parameter / type descriptions etc come from.

You do not need to deploy it with your binary, but it does no harm either. It is also entirely optional in the IDE - just: IntelliSense will be less informative to you without it (it will just display the names and types, etc - not the more verbose method descriptions).

In your own library, use the /// syntax to write your own code comments, and enable the XML file generation in project-properties.

Answer (score 6):

This is the XML documentation for that assembly. This is only used for Intellisense in VisualStudio. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356557/c-sharp-xml-documentation) for details.